# How to dismiss a viewController pushed from a modalViewController without dismissing the modal?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

This is the design of the app:
TabBarController -> NavigationController -> Show ModalViewController -> Push another ViewController on top (by segue)

How can I dismiss the last ViewController without dismissing the ModalViewController?

Comment: You can pop the ViewController, just maintain a reference to it, and call popViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to dismiss the viewController by simply [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated: YES]. The dismiss was dismissing all the modal view controller.

Answer (score 0):

if your design is like this

```
 TabBarController -> NavigationController -> rootviewcontroller -->Show ModalViewController -> Push another ViewController2 on top (by push segue)
```

firstly you cannot push viewcontroller on top of modalviewcontroller , if you try that .
viewcontroller will be pushed on back of modalviewcontroller and when you dismiss that modal viewcontroller you will see viewcontroller2 is shown.